# WPF ComboBoxItem with TextBlock and Button - Dropdown Closing Issue

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ComboBox which as item have a `TextBlock` and `Button`. My requirement is to only close the dropdown when user click on button, not on Textblock or other area around the item. I am able to manage closing of `DropDown` on click of button, but still I am struggling to prevent DropDown to be closed when user click anywhere else except `Button`.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox"  ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <TextBlock Text={Binding}/>
         <Button Content="OK" Width="auto"/>
        </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind [ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.isdropdownopen(v=vs.110).aspx) property with your boolean property.
And you can set this property to false on your button click.

Comment: This seems a solution but , if bind ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen property with a boolean property and will set it false(as default). On which event I should set it true. Means how I will be able to open/reopen Dropdown.

Comment: When you click on combobox it will automatically gets opened.